# Cost effective hand held medical scanner

Tags: measurements, distance-measurement, medical-devices

I am currently doing a summer project where I am tasked with taking precise measurement of skin deformations, whether it be wounds or pimples, the measurement of the z-axis depth is what I am primarily focused on and the goal is sub millimeter accuracy.

I originally tried to use photogrammetry and stereo vision techniques but the accuracy wasn't there. Is it plausible for me to build a cost effective hand held 3D scanner that could give me quantitative 3D data? There are so many measuring techniques when it comes to optical measuring and was hoping someone with more experience could give me some insight on its plausibility since I know little about this field.

Comment: What scanners are already on the market? Which ones have you checked out? How do they work?

Comment: potogrametry can easily do sub millimeter accuracy. Only it dont work on human skin because the subsurface scattering of the skin fools the tracking and depth estimators. Same problem with structured light methods in visible spectrum. but once you step out of visible light the skin nolonger behaves like this so...

Comment: Look into how those orthodontic scanners work. I believe they are formally called intraoral scanners.